# Problem installing Python Poetry on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi, python-poetry

I am setting up the backend of a website by docker and trying to include Python Poetry but run into some errors.
Here's the image of the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv0Qv.png

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of CMD,. Try to use the ENTRYPOINT instead.

Comment: doesn't seems to work. But what is the difference between cmd and entrypoint anyway

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, include your code and the full error message as text (see the [guide to asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Right now, it's impossible to see what the actual error is, since we can't see the full error message. Since the error involves Poetry, you should also include your 'pyproject.toml' file and which Poetry version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#ci-recommendations) installing via pip is completely fine.

You can do it like this (version is pinned for stability):

```
ENV POETRY_VERSION 1.5.1

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
```